# not displaying the row in input type "Supplier"

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi why is the "Supplier" is not displaying while the other data in a row are dispying in input type.  This is a update page and my codes below thanks.

```
<?php
include ('dbcon.php');

$users_id = $_GET['id'];
$SelSql = "SELECT * FROM supplier WHERE id='$users_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $SelSql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$supplier   =   $row['supplier']; 
$status     =   $row['status'];
$remarks    =   $row['remarks'];
}

}else {
$alertMessage="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Theres Nothing to see Here.</div>";
}

?>


<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Supplier" name="supplier" value="<?php echo $supplier; ?>">
```

Comment: I have reviewed and tried you code. Nothing is wrong. The `$supplier` could display in the form. I guess you may check the database, I think the `supplier` column is null in your case. You may check it also by `var_dump($row)` in the `while` loop part.

Comment: its not null, because the other column was displaying except supplier column.

Comment: You code works well in my environment. Did you try to var_dump the `row` array?

Comment: I've change the variable name of supplier in while loop and it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It works fine in my environment.